# When is comparative degree adjectives with no "than" preferable?

Tags: adjectives

Are there any rules / recommendation to using comparative "larger" instead of positive "large" when there is no comparison? What are they (recommendation of course)?
Examples:

*"I, **__, take you, __**, to be my lawfully wedded(husband/wife), to have and to hold, from this day forward, for **better**, for **worse**, for **richer**, for **poorer**..."*

"*The main participants in this market are the **larger** international banks."*(Wikipedia)

Comment: _For better, for worse, for richer, for poorer_ is a fixed liturgical formula, and might as well be in Latin, for all it will tell you about English comparative use. It's archaic grammar, and not normal English. _The larger banks_ is a different matter; it divides the spectrum of bank size into two parts (necessarily with fuzzy boundaries), and refers us to the ones on the `Large` half (also a necessarily fuzzy set). It's just a way of sweeping away details to present a large-scale trend. And also of ignoring inconvenient facts in the service of the trend.

Comment: There are innumerable circumstances when a comparative adjective is used without *than*. A contrasting item is often stated or implied without the explicit use of *than*. *Of the two halves, I'll take the larger.* Or *I was the older brother* [there are clearly two of us, and I came first].

Comment: What @John said. By implication (for me, at least) the number of  banks identified as "large" is likely to be less than those identified as "larger". That's because I envisage the former as being part of a 3-way categorisation (*small, medium,* and *large*, where most instances fall into the middle category). But probably *all* banks would have to be either "larger" or "smaller" (since there is no such category as "mediumer"), so half (or even more) of them could be "larger".

Comment: Right. It's like mentioning a PDE array without bothering to specify the boundary conditions or the number of independent variables.

Comment: I thank all very much for explanation how I should understand the construction. Here is how I explained it before I put my question here: "'Larger' in this context means 'larger than many [of them]', or 'commonly considered as large'". I dare to rephrase my question though: "When (in what context) is it preferable? (Or should I _want_ sometimes to say like wikipedia does in my quote?)"

Answer (score 2):

In a non-searchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, John Lawler presented the following answer:

> *For better, for worse, for richer, for poorer* is a fixed liturgical formula, and might as well be in Latin, for all it will tell you about English comparative use. It’s archaic grammar, and not normal English.
>
> *The larger banks* is a different matter; it divides the spectrum of bank size into two parts (necessarily with fuzzy boundaries), and refers us to the ones on the ‘Large’ half (also a necessarily fuzzy set). It’s just a way of sweeping away details to present a large-scale trend. And also of ignoring inconvenient facts in the service of the trend.

This post is community wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.

Comment: OK, I consider the question as closed, and I am grateful to all contributors.

Answer (score 1):

When is no 'than' preferable to what? It's safe to assume that you mean preferable to the alternative, and you managed to convey your thoughts with fewer words than if you'd said "When is comparative degree adjectives with no “than” preferable to not using 'than'". I would say that it is preferable in any situation where being succinct is desirable and the alternative is implied by the context.

Comment: Why does wikipedia prefer comparative degree in my example? My question in title is: "When is {comparative degree adjectives with no “than”} preferable [to positive degree]?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the difference between: "The main participants in this market are the **larger** international banks."(Wikipedia) and "The main participants in this market are the **large** international banks."

Comment: To me those two sentences could have interchangeable meaning in some situations. The main difference is that the use of 'larger' makes it clear that there is some kind of comparison implied, we aren't including the smaller banks in our statement. If we say 'large' instead then it could be interpreted as saying "The main participants are the international banks, which all happen to be large".

Comment: Thanks again Dave, I am glad I managed to explain question. I also all of a sudden came to a conclusion that there is a semantically similar construction in my native Russian. Reverse literal translation might have been "those international banks that are" (or "seem to be") "larger".